# Excluding transitive dependency more than one level

Tags: java, maven

I have this pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.simas.qlrm</groupId>
            <artifactId>qlrm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The dependency:tree is

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-maven 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ gs-maven ---
[INFO] org.springframework:gs-maven:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- ch.simas.qlrm:qlrm:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.170:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.142 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-23T15:43:19+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Even though I have excluded javax.persistence I'm getting the following warnings while build

```
[WARNING] javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar define 92 overlappping classes:
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.SecondaryTable
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.TableGenerator
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.NamedNativeQueries
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.SecondaryTables
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.JoinTable
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Id
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Embedded
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.EntityResult
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.EntityManager
[WARNING]   - 82 more...
[WARNING] javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar, eclipselink-2.5.1.jar define 24 overlappping classes:
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.ConstructorResult
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.ParameterMode
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Index
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Subgraph
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.ConstraintMode
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Converts
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaUpdate
[WARNING]   - 14 more...
[WARNING] javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar, eclipselink-2.5.1.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar define 80 overlappping classes:
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.criteria.SetJoin
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.CacheRetrieveMode
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.TupleElement
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.metamodel.PluralAttribute
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.AccessType
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.Access
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.metamodel.ManagedType
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute
[WARNING]   - javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder$Trimspec
[WARNING]   - 70 more...
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some .class files
[WARNING] are present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only
[WARNING] one single version of the class is copied in the uberjar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skeep these
[WARNING] warnings, otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts
[WARNING] based on mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above
[WARNING] output
[WARNING] See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Shade+Plugin
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /Users/sivakr/Documents/java/maven_1/target/gs-maven-0.1.0.jar with /Users/sivakr/Documents/java/maven_1/target/gs-maven-0.1.0-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /Users/sivakr/Documents/java/maven_1/dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.214 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-23T15:43:11+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to exclude the duplicate jar's ? And eliminate warnings

**UPDATED** dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-maven 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ gs-maven ---
[INFO] org.springframework:gs-maven:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- ch.simas.qlrm:qlrm:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.170:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.138 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-23T18:11:06+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The POM change to exclude a dependency more than one level away is the same as excluding a dependency exactly one level away.

According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)
if the dependency graph is as follows

```
Project-A
   -> Project-B
        -> Project-D 
              -> Project-E <!-- Exclude this dependency -->
              -> Project-F
   -> Project C
```

to exclude project E in project A POM

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>sample.ProjectE</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
          <artifactId>Project-E</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Then my example should do fine right ? Still throws warnings.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven depdendcy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) output format is:

```
[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]
```

for the dependency:

```
org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.1.0:compile
```

The group is `org.eclipse.persistence` and the artifactId is `javax.persistence`

Your exclusion rule is wrong, the group and artifact are reversed. It should be:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

EDIT: Add maven-shade-plugin configuration

To exclude the dependency from [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) try to add the [exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) to the plugin configuration:

```
<execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </artifactSet>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>hello.HelloWorld</mainClass>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Yes I've updated pom.xml but still I see the same warnings :(

Comment: Can you also update how the dependency tree looks now?

Comment: Updated. Yeah that package was excluded from tree. But still maven build showing the same. Any idea ?

Comment: Updated my answer, too long for a comment. Try adding exclusions to the shade plugin.

Comment: If I add exclusion in maven shade configuration it again shows up in dependency:tree. No changes in warnings.

Comment: I meant to keep it in both sides. If this does not work ... I think we have to wait if someone has another answer. :(